# How to find the value of a Public key from SSH Key in Azure

Tags: azure, ssh-keys

Is there any way to get the value of Public Key from a SSH key in azure. Example I want to get the public key(ssh-rsa AAAAxxxxxxxxx...) using my SSH Key name.

Answer (score 0):

Yes!

When you [generate and store SSH keys in the Azure portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/ssh-keys-portal), they are created and stored as resources of type `Microsoft.Compute/sshPublicKeys`.

So, one natural way to [list your keys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/ssh-keys-portal#list-keys) would be to filter your resources view on the Azure Portal itself.

Also, there are [REST APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/compute/sshpublickeys) available for managing these SSH Public Keys. You can use the [SSH Public Keys - Get](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/compute/sshpublickeys/get) API to retrieve information about an SSH public key by passing in the key name and the resource group that it is in.

Although there are no Azure CLI commands or PowerShell cmdlets available to manage these keys out of the box, you can use the `Invoke-RestMethod` cmdlet to invoke the REST API through PowerShell.

```
PS> $Uri = "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/<subscription-id>/resourceGroups/<>rg-name>/providers/Microsoft.Compute/sshPublicKeys/<ssh-key-name>?api-version=2020-06-01"

PS> $Headers = @{}
PS> $Headers.Add("Authorization", "<token>")

PS> $sshkey = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri $Uri -Headers $Headers
PS> $publickey = $sshkey.properties.publicKey
PS> $publickey

ssh-rsa AAAA....................................t3vhIK4FAfRDVpaw
xFn2DluJNzAo....................................4FEDtj8IghkhocPO
yIUkCfxBJFIc....................................eidRme+6d2SgfOQd
qR3cyViqbMLL....................................UcIjn3iE9/qWn+bj
gzjhQryL1B0r....................................xCOvV/JhLepGFg/K
ipyt0aZrQISv...................Q/BMuWuD8= generated-by-azure\r\n
```

Hope that helps!